# How to check to see if the contents in file A exist in the contents files in a directory

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file that has several lines of text, lets say:

```
cat
dog
rabbit
```

I would like to to traverse a directory to check to see if any text files contain the items in the aforementioned list.

I have tried many of things many different ways. I did not want to post anything because I wanted a fresh start...Fresh line of thinking. I worked the below code to the point that I don't even understand whats going on and Im completely lost. :(

```
#! /usr/bin/python

'''
The purpose of this program
is to search the OS file system
in order to find a txt file that contain the nagios host entries
'''

import os

host_list = open('/path/path/list', 'r')

host = host_list.read()
##for host in host_remove.read():

host_list.close()
#print host

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/path/path/somefolder/"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):

            check_file = os.path.join(root, file)
            #print check_file


            if host.find(check_file): #in check_file:

                print host.find(check_file)                    
                #print host+" is found in "+check_file
                #print os.path.join(root, file)
            else:
                break
```

Comment: The second part of your question was completely off-topic. I removed it.

Comment: Can you share what you've attempted so far?

Comment: The second question was fair? but any who.....

Comment: some one save me!!! im drowning in my own code.

Comment: define: *"contain the items in the aforementioned list"* Do you want to search for a complete line, a complete set of lines, the exact sequence of lines e.g., if a file contains `"watchdog"`; does it match?

Comment: I want to search for an exact string. Whats actually in the file are server names. which may have dots ".". One server name per line. I basically have a serverlist and I would like to know if any file in my directory contains any of those servernames in that list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An analog of [the shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25555032/python2-7-how-to-check-to-see-if-the-contents-in-file-a-exist-in-the-contents-o/25556218#comment39907372_25556218):

```
$ find /path/somefolder/ -name \*.txt -type f -exec grep -wFf /path/list {} +
```

in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import re
import sys

def files_with_matched_lines(topdir, matched):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(topdir, topdown=True):
        dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if not d.startswith('.')] # skip "hidden" dirs
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith(".txt"):
                path = os.path.join(root, filename)
                try:
                    with open(path) as file:
                        for line in file:
                            if matched(line):
                                yield path
                                break
                except EnvironmentError as e:
                    print >>sys.stderr, e

with open('/path/list') as file:
    hosts = file.read().splitlines()
matched = re.compile(r"\b(?:%s)\b" % "|".join(map(re.escape, hosts))).search
for path in files_with_matched_lines("/path/somefolder/", matched):
    print path
```

Comment: J.F. Sebastian, your code works pretty well when I search from a specific directory. However if I search at the root level, your program will inevitably try open a file it does not have access to. How can we create an exception for this?                                                               
    for path in files_with_matched_lines("/", matched):
  File "/Users/dmartin/scripts/python/host_removal/naghstlctv3.py", line 11, in files_with_matched_lines
    with open(path) as file:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/private/etc/racoon/psk.txt'

Comment: I forgot to add. Your code is perfectly pythonic because it runs on both unix and windows. I just tried it. I only had to make a small modification to accept raw strings (r) in the two places where the files are opened. the only thing left to do is add an exception so that it does not error out when the program does not have access to the file its trying to search.

Comment: @user3655020: I've updated the code to ignore errors while reading a file

Comment: +1 for portability, but the find line is so much better, especially if you want to chain it as part of a larger script.

Comment: beautiful... J.F. Sebastian

Comment: @user3655020: You already did. It is enough to mark appropriate answer as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Python is way, way overkill for this task. Just use `grep`:

```
$ grep -wFf list_of_needles.txt some_target.txt
```

If you really need to use Python, wrap a `grep` call in `subprocess` or similar.

Comment: Well I appreciate it may be over kill. I actually have bash scripts that does what I need in peaces. I choose to use python. mostly to help learn the language. I hate doing exercises from books. I find that necessity is the mother of invention. I tend to learn well, when i code things that I actually need. I could have also used the OS commands in python, but I wanted to be pythonic..... This actually brings me to another question, which I hope is not off topic.... seeing that this is overkill for python..What, in your opinion is python used for?

Comment: `find /path/path/somefolder/ -name \*.txt -exec grep -xFf hosts /path/path/list {} +`

Comment: yep, thats one of the ways its done in bash.... How do i do it in python without using bash?

Comment: I suggest using the right tool for the job. If you want to use a table saw to polish the car, go for it. Specifically, if you really need to solve the problem in Python, make a system call with `subprocess` (look it up) and collect standard output via that library's functionality (look it up).

Comment: Hi, I think we may be getting some where. I have made systems calls to do other task. I'm comfortable doing it that way. The reason that I'm choosing to use python code vs system calls or bash is because I want to have an idea of how to do these regardless of the OS. I know Linux(bash). What would happen if I needed to run this program on Windows or android? my idea is code something that could be used on any os with few changes. Is this possible?

Comment: Use regular expressions, testing every line of every text file in your directory of interest, maybe. It will be very slow, as most anything in Python will be that involves file I/O, parsing, regular expressions, any other useful task, etc. Python is the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: Okay, forgive my noobie question. What are python tools good for?

Answer (score 0):

I've made some minor changes to the algorytms provided by J.F. Sebastian. 
The changes will ask for user input. It will also run on windows with no issues.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import re
import sys

contents = raw_input("Please provide the full path and file name that contains the items you would like to search for \n")
print "\n"
print "\n"
direct = raw_input("Please provide the directory you would like to search. \
Use C:/, if you want to search the root directory on a windows machine\n")

def files_with_matched_lines(topdir, matched):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(topdir, topdown=True):
        dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if not d.startswith('.')] # skip "hidden" dirs
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith(".txt"):
                path = os.path.join(root, filename)
                try:
                    with open(path) as file:
                        for line in file:
                            if matched(line):
                                yield path
                                break
                except EnvironmentError as e:
                    print >>sys.stderr, e

with open(contents) as file:
    hosts = file.read().splitlines()
matched = re.compile(r"\b(?:%s)\b" % "|".join(map(re.escape, hosts))).search
for path in files_with_matched_lines(direct, matched):
    print path
```